# Integrate graphite metrics with bosun

Tags: monitoring, graphite, bosun

I am running Docker container for bosun. I want to integrate the graphite metrics with bosun. 
What are the configuration changes that need to be done for this?

Comment: Just opened a ticket for the same thing ! 
https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/issues/1250

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation you linked, you must set the `graphiteHost` in the config:

> graphiteHost: an ip, hostname, ip:port, hostname:port or a URL,
>   defaults to standard http/https ports, defaults to “/render” path. Any
>   non-zero path (even “/” overrides path)

The graphing page and items page in Bosun only work with OpenTSDB as the backend. However, you can still you the expression page, dashboard, and config editor. When you use expressions that return a `seriesSet` as the [graphite query functions](https://bosun.org/expressions.html#graphite-query-functions) do, you will see a graph tab on the expression tabe. You can also use the `.Graph` and `.GraphAll` template functions with graphite. So it is largely functional.

There is also an [example graphite alert](https://bosun.org/examples.html#graphite-anomalous-traffic-volume-per-country) in the [examples](https://bosun.org/examples.html) part of the documentation.

Comment: thanks @Kyle
to set the graphiteHost which config file needs to be edited?

Comment: Bosun's config file, which also contains all the alerting rules and templates.  The location of the file is specified by passing a value to the `-c` flag of the bosun command: `./bosun -h
Usage of ./bosun:
  -c="dev.conf": config file location`

Answer (score 4):

@kyle-brandt's answer is okay and I gave it an upvote but it and the Bosun docs don't really explain enough of how to use a Graphite that you don't host, i.e. hostedgraphite.com.  Using the docs and some trial and error I figured things out. So here it goes:

1. Make a Graphite API key: http://docs.hostedgraphite.com/advanced/access-keys.html (you should whitelist IP addresses).  Let's say you got `https://www.hostedgraphite.com/deadbeef/431-831/graphite/`.
2. Create `data.conf` with:

   `tsdbHost = localhost:4242
   stateFile = /data/bosun.state
   graphiteHost = https://www.hostedgraphite.com/deadbeef/431-831/graphite/render`
3. Start the Docker container:

   `` docker run -d \
   -p 80:8070 \
   --name=bosun \
   -v `pwd`/bosun.conf:/data/bosun.conf \
   stackexchange/bosun ``

   Note that I didn't do the 4242 port mapping because I'm getting my data just from hostedgraphite.com and I mapped 8070 to 80 so that I don't have to specify the port when going to Bosun in the browser.
4. Adding expressions: The [docs](http://bosun.org/expressions#graphite-query-functions) say to use `GraphiteQuery` but that didn't work for me, `graphite` worked instead.  For example: `graphite("my.long.metric.name.for.some.method", "10m", "", "")`.  There is also an [example graphite alert](https://bosun.org/examples.html#graphite-anomalous-traffic-volume-per-country) in the [examples](https://bosun.org/examples.html) part of the documentation (thanks @kyle-brandt).

Comment: much appreciated, the bosun docs really fall apart here.  you can also edit the config in your live container (which is obviously short term) with `docker exec -it <id> bash` then a bit of `export TERM=xterm` `nano /data/boson.conf` and `kill -HUP 1` or just `supervisorctl restart bosun`